# App Store Promo Codes - What happens if used after a new version is released

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

App Store Promo Codes - What happens if one is used after a new version is released?

For example, if I give out promo codes for app version 1.4. And then I release 1.41. Would the version codes for v 1.4 still be usable?

Comment: I believe promo codes can only be redeemed for specific version.  I don't have anything specific from Apple to point to as the official policy but I remember when I offered codes last year that this was correct (that's why I'm not adding this as an answer yet).

Answer (score 1):

Once you release an app update, all previous promo codes become invalid and promo codes cannot be used. They also expire four weeks from the day they’re generated.

Comment: wow that's terribly inconvenient. what if you release an app update for bug reasons or something after giving promo codes out?